# Expected expression, got '}', can't find error anywhere

Tags: javascript, html

Very basic JS user, learning for a class right now so ignore any optimizations to the code or anything that could be made. 
Part of the assignment is creating this button that calculates a final cost given variables. Upon clicking the button, FireFox gives me an error: "expected expression, got '}'"
I don't see any open brackets or other syntax errors, any help?

```
<button id="totalSales" onclick = "
                totalCost = (totalCost + burgerOnePrice*Number(burgerOne.value));
                totalCost = (totalCost + burgerTwoPrice*Number(burgerTwo.value));
                totalCost = (totlCost + burgerThreePrice*Number(burgerThree.value));
                totalCost = totalCost*(1+tip);

                    if (useCard==1) {

                        if (Number(balance.value) >= totalCost) {
                            totalCost = 0;
                            cardBalance = cardBalance-totalCost;
                            balance.value = cardBalance;
                            finalCost.value = totalCost;

                        } else {
                        totalCost = (totalCost-Number(balance.value));
                            balance.value = "$0.00";
                            finalCost.value = totalCost;
                        }

                    } else if (useCard==0) {
                        totalCost = totalCost;
                        finalCost.value = totalCost;
                    }


                 " >Calculate Total</button> 
                 <br>

        <input type="text" id="finalCost" value="" size="3" readonly="true" />
```

Comment: Please put it into a function. Please. Please. Please.

Comment: This logic doesn't look correct: totalCost = 0; cardBalance = cardBalance-totalCost;

Answer (score 5):

The first time you use `"` in your JavaScript, you're ending the `onclick="..."` attribute, leading to a syntax error.

You shouldn't be cramming that much JavaScript into your DOM. Put it in a function, and call the function from your event handler.

Comment: Could have been worse, he could have crammed it all on one line. :)

Answer (score 1):

In this line `balance.value = "$0.00";` you are using double quotes `"`
This makes the browser think the `onclick` ended there, and from then on, it just can't make heads or tails of anything.

But you shouldn't be writing that much code inside html, I would even say that you shouldn't even use `onclick` inside html elements.

It is a much better idea to use the `addEventListener` method in a separate .js file.

Answer (score 0):

You should not write your javascript code into your HTML tag.

First, create js function in script tag

```
    function myFunction() {
  totalCost = (totalCost + burgerOnePrice * Number(burgerOne.value));
  totalCost = (totalCost + burgerTwoPrice * Number(burgerTwo.value));
  totalCost = (totlCost + burgerThreePrice * Number(burgerThree.value));
  totalCost = totalCost * (1 + tip);

  if (useCard == 1) {

    if (Number(balance.value) >= totalCost) {
      totalCost = 0;
      cardBalance = cardBalance - totalCost;
      balance.value = cardBalance;
      finalCost.value = totalCost;

    } else {
      totalCost = (totalCost - Number(balance.value));
      balance.value = $0.00;
      finalCost.value = totalCost;
    }

  } else if (useCard == 0) {
    totalCost = totalCost;
    finalCost.value = totalCost;
  }

}
```

then use html onclick event parameter like that.

```
<button onclick="myFunction();" id="totalSales">Calculate Total</button>
```